# jQuery not fading to correct image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple matrix style slideshow where one out of four images fades to the next image from an array. The index that correlates to position on the screen increments and the and the index for the image url increments. At 3, I reset imagePosition to restart at 0, and when the imageUrl index reaches the length of the array, I also reset.

The problem however is that the image resets with the same image as the one that was already there in that position. When I log the url, its different, but the dom does not update & the link when I inspect remains the same.

I have tried using a random index under 4, and that seems to work, but I need it to iterate through all spots on screen in order.

fadeToImage is being called every 5 seconds and passes the same array.

(I know the code is repetitive, going to refactor after)

```js
var urlArray = ["http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/EranGOTGif0007.gif", "https://jimpix.co.uk/ink/ecards/angif_octopus.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/cmefPHy.gif", "http://miscmedia-9gag-fun.9cache.com/images/thumbnail-facebook/1449833420.8507_ePysAs_n.jpg", "https://media.giphy.com/media/9fbYYzdf6BbQA/giphy.gif", "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/552a5cc4e4b059a56a050501/565f6b57e4b0d9b44ab87107/566024f5e4b0354e5b79dd24/1449141991793/NYCGifathon12.gif", "http://67.media.tumblr.com/50af8ed4e4afcc4530c83057db147a91/tumblr_nltc6y6pau1rx5rfmo1_1280.gif"];

setInterval(function() {
  fadeToImage(urlArray);
}, 5000);

var cycled = false;
var count = 4;
var imagePosition=0;
function fadeToImage(urlArray)
{
    if (cycled === false){
      count = 4;
      imagePosition=0;
        console.log("setting first images")
        $(".display-image-0").attr("style", "background:url(\"" + urlArray[0] + "\"); background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; transform: rotate(90deg);");
        $(".display-image-1").attr("style", "background:url(\"" + urlArray[1] + "\"); background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; transform: rotate(90deg);");
        $(".display-image-2").attr("style", "background:url(\"" + urlArray[2] + "\"); background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; transform: rotate(90deg);");
        $(".display-image-3").attr("style", "background:url(\"" + urlArray[3] + "\"); background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; transform: rotate(90deg);");
        cycled = true;
    } else {
        if (imagePosition < 4) {
            console.log(count)
            if (count < urlArray.length) {
                console.log("image position less than 4, count < array", imagePosition, count, urlArray[count] )
                $(".display-image-" + imagePosition).fadeTo(1000, 0, function () {
                    $(".display-image-" + imagePosition).attr("style", "background:url(\"" + urlArray[count] + "\"); background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; transform: rotate(90deg);");
                }).fadeTo(2000, 1);
                count++;
            } else {
                cycled = false;
            }
            imagePosition++;
        } else {
            imagePosition = 0;
            if (count < urlArray.length) {
                $(".display-image-" + imagePosition).fadeTo(1000, 0, function () {
                    $(".display-image-" + imagePosition).attr("style", "background:url(\"" + urlArray[count] + "\"); background-size: auto 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; transform: rotate(90deg);");
                }).fadeTo(2000, 1);
                count++;
            } else {
                 cycled = false;
            }
            imagePosition++;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.display-image-0 {
    position:   fixed;
    left:       0px;
    top:        0px;
    height:     33%;
    width:      50%;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.display-image-1 {
    position:   fixed;
    right:      0px;
    top:        0px;
    height:     33%;
    width:      50%;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.display-image-2 {
    position:   fixed;
    left:       0px;
    bottom:     0px;
    height:     33%;
    width:      50%;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.display-image-3 {
    position:   fixed;
    right:       0px;
    bottom:        0px;
    height:     33%;
    width:      50%;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-image-0"></div>
<div class="display-image-1"></div><div class="display-image-2"></div>
<div class="display-image-3"></div>
```

Comment: Can't able to run the script using the `Run code snippet` button provided here, Can you please put this as a workable code in JSFiddle and share us the link?

Comment: You should be able to Run Code Snippet now

Comment: `count++` so it goes UP from 4? Is that right? so the conditional  always fails?

Comment: Count refers to the index in the urlArray, not the index of the four display images. no conditional always fails, it just wont show any images unless are are more than 4 to be shown.

Comment: So using that logic delete the entire conditional(s) as `if (count < urlArray.length) {` is always false since `count>=4` is always true and if `urlArray.length` is 4 then they never execute that part, it being false always (unless I misread it somehow)

Comment: Not sure if I am following. The first iteration, I am manually setting the background images to the first four urls: `background:url(\"" + urlArray[0] + "\")` etc. I am then assigning count to equal 4 because we do not need the first 4 images, changing `cycled` to true so it does not implicitly assign bg images. Then, if current imagePos is less than 4, i am assigning that div a url from array with count index. (until that index == length of array, then reseting again).

Comment: Yea, I appear to have misread the length of the array which is 7 :) my bad

Answer (score 0):

I changed the second jQuery selector, where I am assigning style attribute to `$(this)` and it worked.

Comment: I  don't think that second conditional executes I put this in and it never alerts: `else {
      imagePosition = 0;
      alert("hi");`

Comment: I noticed that as well, code was redundant. Thanks for your help!